# data set convert to matrix with tupel

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to convert a part of my data to make it compatible with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854873

The data is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` with:

```
      result  data_1  data_2
1    1.523     4        1223
3    1.33     84        1534
```

Some index values might be removed, therefore 1, 3, ...

It should be a tuple with data values and the result. The type in the solution was `scipy.sparse._coo.coo_matrix`, like:

```
  (4, 1223) 1.523
  (84, 1534) 1.33
```

Just `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(df.values)` seems to mix the data.

```
  (0, 0)    1.523
  (0, 1)    1.53
  (0, 24)   1.92
  : :
  (2, 151)  123.0
  (2, 142)  834.0
```

How can I generate a compatible matrix?

Comment: That `coo` display with tuple, is just a display.  It isn't actually a list or array with tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['tuple'] = list(zip(df.data_1, df.data_2))
result = df[['tuple', 'result']].to_numpy()
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[(4, 1223) 1.523]
 [(84, 1534) 1.33]]
```

Source:
[How to form tuple column from two columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031056/how-to-form-tuple-column-from-two-columns-in-pandas)
[Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the data columns, then apply `tuple` on `axis=1` which will essentially create the tuple out of row values, I'm assigning it as a new column as the output you've mentioned is not clear if its an array or dataframe, but I think you should be able to move forward with the remaining outcome you need.

```py
>>> df.assign(data=df.filter(like='data').apply(tuple, axis=1))

   result  data_1  data_2        data
1   1.523       4    1223   (4, 1223)
3   1.330      84    1534  (84, 1534)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the sparse matrix (not just copy its display) with:

```
In [87]: from scipy import sparse
```

3 arrays that can be derived from columns of the dataframe:

```
In [88]: data = np.array([1.523, 1.33])    
In [89]: row = np.array([4,84])    
In [90]: col = np.array([1223, 1534])
```

The actual matrix:

```
In [91]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row, col)))
```

The `repr` display:

```
In [92]: M
Out[92]: 
<85x1535 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

and its `str` display:

```
In [93]: print(M)
  (4, 1223) 1.523
  (84, 1534)    1.33
```

This `M.shape` is derived from the max values of the arrays; in practice you might want to specify a larger shape.

`M.toarray()` creates a numpy array from this, but with that shape it will be too large to display.

I'm not sure how the dataframe was derived from such a matrix.